# Copiar texto de varios scrolledtext de varias pestañas

Tags: python-3.x

estoy creando una GUI que tiene una pantalla principal y de esa pantalla principal, tiene 2 botones que me llaman a una clase cada uno:

ejemplo botón1 llama a la clase Desviacion, en esta clase Desviacion tengo varios objetos, label, scrolledtext etc etc, llamo a la clase Desviacion la veces que sean necesarias

mi problema es que al intentar hacer un copy de un scrolledtext de cualquiera de las pestañas activas, solo me copia el texto de la última pestaña..

El copiar lo hago a través de un menu contextual, con una opción de copiar, el menú lo tengo creado en la ventana principal y hace referencia a los scrolledtext de la clase Desviacion.

```
`def menu_clickDerecho(self):
     self.menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
     self.menu.add_command(label="  Copiar", 
                             image=self.copy2_icon,
                             compound=LEFT,
                             background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
                             activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
                             font=('Trajan', 11),
                             command=lambda:self.clickDerecho_copy(None))
     self.menu.add_command(label="  Cerrar pestaña", 
                             image=self.cerrar_icon,
                             compound=LEFT,
                             background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
                             activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
                             font=('Trajan', 11),
                             command=self.cerrar_pestaña)
     self.menuTop = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)


def display_menu_clickDerecho(self, event):
     try:
         self.menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
     except:
         self.menu.grab_release()

 def clickDerecho_copy(self, event):
     desviacion.fr2_text3.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
     desviacion.fr2_text2.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
     desviacion.fr3_text1.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
     desviacion.fr3_text2.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
     desviacion.fr3_text3.event_generate("<<Copy>>")`
```

Como se ve en el código tengo 3 funciones, una me crea el menú, otro que me lo muestra y otro que genera un copy del texto seleccionado.

Como puedo hacer que cada pestaña independiente, al seleccionar un texto se copié ese texto??, Por favor necesito ayuda y si queréis más información os cuento.
Gracias

Sistema operativo Linux y Python 3.6.8
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]